# is copyright string in gpl'ed program guarded from modification?

Tags: licensing, gpl

is copyright string in gpl'ed program guarded from modification, by gpl or by laws? for example, is it possible to change "2001-2010" to "2010 to 2010"? or maybe change spelling of copyright holder name or translate copyright holder name or the word "copyright" to other language? or remove additional info that is not copyright notice itself, for example, names of authors or sponsors, if there is any, and leave only copyright info? or add some additional words like "modified by"?

Comment: Never change the spelling of the copyright holder's name. If the name is written in a non-latin alphabet, you could add a transliteration in addition to the original version.

Answer (score 4):

The copyright string is not part of the license.  If you read [How to Use GNU Licenses for your own software](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-howto.html), you will see that the copyright string is something that is *added to each source file by the author.*

> The process involves adding two elements to each source file of your program: a copyright notice (such as “Copyright 1999 Terry Jones”), and a statement of copying permission, saying that the program is distributed under the terms of the GNU General Public License
>
> If you have copied code from other programs covered by the same license, copy their copyright notices too. Put all the copyright notices together, right near the top of each file.

Changing someone else's copyright provision would be tantamount to fraud.  You can't do it anywhere else, so I don't see why you would be able to do it when applying the GPL.